Scroll a view to a position

As in the picture, i have to 2 textviews: "scan card" and "scan badge". on click of any of the item, it scrolls horizontally to the center and top of the circular button. how to implement this in xml and kotlin? 
To give an overview of the screen , it's screen where camera is used to capture images. "scan card" and "scan badge" are like 2 modes which can be selected and scrolled. this is typical behaviour in most camera apps but couldn't think how to implement it.
